# When I try to install VIM i am getting this error. Pls suggest solutions

Tags: vim

When I try to install VIM I am getting this error:

```
sandy@sandy-Rev-1-0:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for sandy: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Do you have apt running in another terminal?

Comment: Or Synaptic or the Software Center open?

Answer (score 1):

You get that error if another package-manager program is running and has locked the apt packaging system. APT can only be managed by one program at the time, it is not designed to allow concurrent access to the APT database.

To solve the problem run the commend `fuser -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock` to get the program holding the lock. Close that program first and then try again.

br

Comment: Why the down-vote?